# How to vertically center text within a grid row in css

Tags: html, css

[Here is the code for a minimally reproducible example of the problem I am having.
I looked within all the other posts, and tried them, but they didnt work for some reason.]

When you load the example, the small text wont align with the big text, presumably because it is inside a row. Is there a way to make Small_Text vertically aligned with Big_Text?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            /* GRID AREA SYNTAX REFERENCE:
        grid-row-start, grid-column-start, grid-row-end, grid-column-end
        */
            body {
                display: grid;
                grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
                grid-column-gap: 10px;
                /*Body Border Here for better visibility.*/
                border: 1px solid black;
            }
            .c1 {
                grid-area: 1 / 1 / 2 / 2;
                border: 1px solid black;
                text-align: center;
            }
            .c2 {
                grid-area: 1 / 2 / 2 / 3;
                border: 1px solid black;
                text-align: center;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1 class="c1">Big_Text</h1>
        <p class="c2">Small_Text</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `align-items:center`

```css
body {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-column-gap: 10px;
  /*Body Border Here for better visibility.*/
  border: 1px solid black;
  align-items: center;
}

.c1 {
  grid-area: 1 / 1 / 2 / 2;
  border: 1px solid black;
  text-align: center;
}

.c2 {
  grid-area: 1 / 2 / 2 / 3;
  border: 1px solid black;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<h1 class="c1">Big_Text</h1>
<p class="c2">Small_Text</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe add `align-items:center` to the parent element (which is `body`)

The `align-items:center` will remove whitespace so a solution isto `padding` to add whitespace

se padding to change the whitespace

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            /* GRID AREA SYNTAX REFERENCE:
        grid-row-start, grid-column-start, grid-row-end, grid-column-end
        */
            body {
                display: grid;
                grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
                grid-column-gap: 10px;
                /*Body Border Here for better visibility.*/
                border: 1px solid black;
                align-items:center;

            }
            .c1 {
                grid-area: 1 / 1 / 2 / 2;
                border: 1px solid black;
                text-align: center;
            }
            .c2 {
                padding:10px;
                grid-area: 1 / 2 / 2 / 3;
                border: 1px solid black;
                text-align: center;
     
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1 class="c1">Big_Text</h1>
        <p class="c2">all_Texmall_Texmall_Texmall_Tex</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: [Those aren't even close to being aligned](https://i.postimg.cc/PJNqJ4zV/Screen-Shot-2022-03-15-at-11-11-44-PM.png)

Comment: @AbeShalash,I am confused, the image you are giving doesn't make sense (the horizontial line doesn't start from the center)???

Comment: I believe OP wants to align them at the top, there's a weird vertical padding that's increasing as the font size increases

Comment: @AbeShalash, by adding the padding, it is still vertical align because we both add padding to top and bottom